# Can VS be made to eval a debug watch even while the application is still running?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Normally in Visual Studio, a watch cannot be evaluated unless the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint.  Is there a trick or add-on to make Visual Studio evaluate a watch while the application is still running?  For example, evaluate the watch every time execution passes a point in the code while it's still running and without changing the code to insert statements like `Debug.WriteLine`.

Not sure this is possible, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Set a breakpoint at the location where you'd want to see the value.  Right-click the breakpoint and choose "When Hit...".  Tick "Print a message" and write an expression like { value }.  The message is displayed in the Output window while your program runs.

Comment: Even in this mode the application is not running when the value is printed out.  The application is paused, the value evaluated, and then the application continues running again.

Comment: Hmya, threads are paused all the time.  Not sure if it makes a difference if the scheduler does it or the debugger.  Not one you'd easily notice anyway, other than that it runs slower.

Comment: I was hoping "When hit" would allow for watches to be evaluated, but this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that using compiler directives.

```
#if DEBUG
     Debug.WriteLine
#end if
```

Comment: The idea is to not change code.  I don't wish to recompile with new debug statements every time I find a new method I want to debug.  Moreover, I'd have to rollback those edits since I can't check them into source control in that form.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible to do.  The evaluation feature in Visual Studio is a stack frame based mechanism.  That is that every evaluation is done in the context of a given stack frame (as viewed through the stack window).  When the program is running the set of stack frames is currently changing and hence it's not possible to do a stable evaluation.

Additionally there are other limitations in the CLR which prevent this from managed code.  It's not possible for instance to execute a function unless the debugee process is in a very specific state.